# How do I access current_page value in views twig template?

Tags: views, theming

In `views-view.html.twig`, I'm trying `pager['#views_plugin'].current_page`, but don't get any value.

[image]

Comment: In fact, after more testing, it seems that the value, for some reason, is not printed by kint(), but it works well in an if statement.